# What's the best website for showcasing my work to the public?

Tags: web, portfolio, promotion

Wondering which website is more popular for posting own photography art and maybe get some feedback from community in other words a way to carry photography to mass public. FB is not the right place.

Comment: +1 I have the same "issue" :) I created a flickr profile, but not a single view for about a week :D

Comment: In the intent to get feedback your question is somewhat duplicate to the question "What's the best way to get constructive critique of your photographs?" http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4698/2317

Comment: In addition to what @Leonidas suggests, there's a number of related questions like [What are the best sites to share photo galleries with friends?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/295) and [What is a good pre-built website platform for displaying my photos?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/).

Comment: An important question is: _why_ do you want feedback? Do you want artistic or technical critique, or advice on marketing/promotion, or do you want to generate positive buzz?

Comment: @mattdm: Mostly to generate positive buzz and have some motivation for learning more, achieving more skills.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flickr is definitely a good fit for what you're after:

1. It's **public** by default (unlike Facebook which tends to be private).
2. It's **huge**: it definitely ticks your "mass public" box.
3. It has excellent **social features** that make it very easy to interact with new users (people you don't already know) and get your photos seen.
4. It [doesn't over-compress your images](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12423/does-flickr-recompress-jpegs-after-upload) (like Facebook does) so it's a great place for a high-quality **showcase**.

In response to Kiril Kirov's comment ("I created a flickr profile, but not a single view for about a week :D"), it sounds like you're not using Flickr to its full potential. If you want other people to notice your work, try the following:

1. Give your photos meaningful **titles, descriptions and tags** to ensure they appear in search results.
2. Add your photos to relevant **[groups](http://www.flickr.com/groups/)** and join in the group discussions.
3. Find other users whose work you like and add them as a **contact**. It's not obligatory to reciprocate but many people will. At the very least, they'll usually check out your stream to see who you are.
4. Look for other photos you like and **comment/favourite** them. Again, there's no guarantee people will reciprocate but many do.
5. Join a Flickr group local to your area and go along to a **meet-up**. (If they don't seem to have them, try arranging one! If there's no group, create one!)

Even though Flickr is public by default, you do have to invest some time in it before you'll come to other people's attention. But the same is true of any other photo site. Plenty of people choose other sites (such as [500px](http://500px.com/), [SmugMug](http://www.smugmug.com/) or [Zenfolio](http://www.zenfolio.com/)), often because they have a more professional "portfolio" look, but for social features Flickr just can't be beaten.

Comment: Oh, and one big **don't** to add to that list: don't leave comments along the lines of "Cool shot, please view my photostream". They look like spam and people will ignore them (or even block you). Make your comments mean something, even if secretly you're still fishing for views. ;)

Answer (score 11):

An alternative to Flickr is [500px.com](http://500px.com/). I like the fact that users can provide a rating on any uploads and how you display your photos is more flexible than Flickr

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, Google+ is becoming a fantastic place to showcase photos. It seems to be mostly inhabited by photographers, and the community is huge.

Comment: I am using Google+, but again as in the facebook, it's limited only to your friends(circles), unless I miss some key feature of how to expose to thousands of community people who I don't know.

Comment: When you share something you can share to a circle that you're following, and they will all see it. I followed 800 photographers, and I post pictures to the photography circle.

Comment: how can I find this "photography circle"?

Comment: You can mark posts as public, in which case they'll be available to everyone, but unless someone is either a) looking for random public posts or b) following you specifically, they won't see it.

Comment: @Michael, You can find photographers [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/105237212888595777019/posts/Ky7XYX72czj), then just add them to your circle...

Comment: @benmanbs: It's just a list of users. It's not like a single circle which I can add and have dozens to share. Have to add them one by one, which will send them notification that I have added them and so on.. don't want to bug people with this. So it's not a best option.

Comment: @mattdm: marking a post public doesn't drive people to your post.

Comment: @Michael: it certainly does not — that's what I said. :) If Google+ let someone I don't know arbitrarily force posts into my stream, I'd opt-out _so fast_.

Comment: @Michael, that is a valid point, and a problem many users have brought up to the G+ dev team. I suspect that that ability is in the making.

Answer (score 3):

[1x.com](http://1x.com) is another alternative. It's a bit more exclusive - each image must be approved - but you can get more in-depth critique than at most sites (where you get mostly "nice shot" or "love this!").  I don't know how well-known it is, and you can't just upload all your stuff there, as it has to be approved, but worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

[DeviantART](http://www.deviantart.com) is my favorite site to publish photos and get feedback as well. It has a great interface, active huge community, accepts all kinds of art not just photography, and most importantly it has "groups" which is simply a gathering of people for a topic may it be general as "photography" or specific to just one type of photography. And the forums are great and very active as well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are wanting feedback on all your images or just ones you select. If you want to put a collection online and have it open to comments, Flickr is the standard.

If you want to just post the odd photo for critique, then you're better off going to a forum. [Digital Photography School](http://digital-photography-school.com/forum/) has a good forum where you can either post an image just to 'show off', or post it for critique.

Comment: Seems like in Flickr I can only share with the followers, I mean my photos will not pop into someones screen if I don't know them

Comment: Well, Photobucket allows you to make public galleries, though I'm not sure if it allows comments.

Comment: Doesn't Flickr allow this(public galleries), too?

Comment: The only public place I've seen on Flickr is Today's Interestingness. What does it take to have my photos exposed there?

Comment: @Michael: All of Flickr is public! (Apart from photos you specifically mark as private.) Forget about Interestingness - nobody knows how to get photos into that! Focus on Groups and search results: those are much more straightforward routes to getting your photos seen.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some exposure on Flickr (i.e. not 0 views), you'll need to post your photo to your relevant social networks (Facebook/Twitter), but also look through the list of groups for groups you could submit your photo to. I usually look for the ones with a moderately useful amount of activity and join them.

The other thing is to add as many photographers as contacts as you would like to. Don't just add everyone, but if someone posts something interesting, add them, then you'll see suggestions for other people and so on. The more people you can expose your photos to, the more likely you'll get both views and feedback/favourites.

It's just like everything else. There's millions of Flickr users and without any sort of "advertising", your shots are going to fall into the ether.