# good free photography web hosting

Tags: web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best website for showcasing my work to the public?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14519/whats-the-best-website-for-showcasing-my-work-to-the-public)

Hi this is my first post. I am looking to build my own website to display my photos in a professionally done manner. What is a good free photography web hosting service that's easy to use but still gives me some design control?(my programming skills are very limited)

Comment: This previous post should give you all the answers.

http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14519/whats-the-best-website-for-showcasing-my-work-to-the-public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need both web hosting AND design - one option in (in the UK) 1&1 - they offer hosting and simple package based template sites. 
If the templates on offer are not suitable for you, i would go with a wordpress template - you will need to buy hosting separately though.

wordpress templates offer you some creative control and there isnt a huge amount of coding involved.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a hosting package sorted I would highly recommend self hosted [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) with a custom theme

WordPress is:

- Easy to use
- Fast
- SEO optimised (Google likes it)
- Customisable but not complex
- Content is easy to create and manage
- VAST array of plugins
- its FREE!

Then get yourself a photography specific theme

- Photocrati is a good place to start - http://www.photocrati.com/ (not free but very good)
- There are free ones out there to, so hunt around - but watch out for hidden embedded adverts
- here is a good place to find photography themes for WordPress http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/08/wordpress-photography-themes.html

Then you can take [What's the best website for showcasing my work to the public?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14519/whats-the-best-website-for-showcasing-my-work-to-the-public) and have flickr hosted images displayed on your site

As an example my website is WordPress and a custom theme http://www.robertbradley.co.uk